# Gatsby issue - The list of posts didn't show up despite no errors shown under console and no error with Graphql

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

Background: Newbie...Learning React + Gatsby on weekend

Problem: What i'm trying to achieve here is - If the post equal to "blog" tag, generate a list of post with title. When i try to console.log(tag.name), i could see those tags under console (no errors) but nothing shows up on webpage (if it works well, there should be a list of post). I changed the array index but it wasn't working too. Appreciate if you could share what went wrong?

```
      <ul>
          {wpPosts.map(wpPost => {
            wpPost.tags.nodes.map(tag => {
              console.log(tag.name)

              if (tag.name === "Blog") {
                return (
                  <div>
                    <li>{tag.title}</li>
                  </div>
                )
              }
            })
          })}
        </ul>



  const data = useStaticQuery(
    graphql`
      query {
        allWpPost(sort: { fields: date, order: DESC }, limit: 10) {
          nodes {
            excerpt
            slug
            uri
            title
            date(formatString: "MMMM DD, YYYY")
            tags {
              nodes {
                name
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `
  )

  const wpPosts = data.allWpPost.nodes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not returning the second `map` loop:

```
  <ul>
      {wpPosts.map(wpPost => {
        return wpPost.tags.nodes.map(tag => {
          console.log(tag.name)

          if (tag.name === "Blog") {
            return (
              <div>
                <li>{tag.title}</li>
              </div>
            )
          }
        })
      })}
    </ul>
```

Comment: @ Ferran, it's solved. gosh i missed that part....Thank you !